# What is diffrence between getstoreconfig and getstoreconfigflag?

Tags: configuration, config, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

In magento 1.9 What is diffrence between getstoreconfig() and getstoreconfigflag() methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The methods look like this:

```
    public static function getStoreConfig($path, $store = null)
    {
        return self::app()->getStore($store)->getConfig($path);
    }

    public static function getStoreConfigFlag($path, $store = null)
    {
        $flag = strtolower(self::getStoreConfig($path, $store));
        if (!empty($flag) && 'false' !== $flag) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The only difference is that `getStoreConfig()` will return the **exact value** while `getStoreConfigFlag()` returns **boolean true or false.**

Both methods send us to `Mage_Core_Model_Store::getConfig()`.